# How to allow www-data to create a folder with read, write and execute permission

Tags: 14.04, permissions, php, vps, mkdir

How do I create a directory with read, write and execute permission in ubuntu 14.04.

I have a web-app written in php and I am using

```
<?php mkdir('/items/folder', 0777, true); ?>
```

to create folders but the its not assigning the right permission to my folders, even using chomd on my php script fails.

The app is on a digitalocean vps.OS is ubuntu 14.04.

What can I do?

Comment: there is no answer in that question also

Comment: That does not mean you can post duplicate questions.

Comment: am sorry about that, just trying to make the question plain as possible as it can be